# This code works fine as a dice, but i want it to repeat again after each roll, thank you if answers

Tags: python, loops

I know i have to write a for or while loop, the code is this:

```
import random

trigger = input("Press T to roll dice: ")

if trigger.upper() == "T":
    def roll():
        dice = random.randint(1, 6)
        print(f"Your number is: {dice}")
    roll()
else:
    print("Invalid key, press T to roll")
```

Comment: Put `while True:` around everything and `break` when you want it to stop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A version that keeps looping until the user inputs "q":

```py
import random

while True:
    trigger = input("Press T to roll dice (or q to quit): ")
    if trigger.upper()=="Q":
        break

    if trigger.upper() == "T":
        def roll():
            dice = random.randint(1, 6)
            print(f"Your number is: {dice}")
        roll()
    else:
        print("Invalid key, press T to roll")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
#repeat this loop 10 times
for i in range(1,10):
    trigger = input("Press T to roll dice: ")

    if trigger.upper() == "T":
        def roll():
            dice = random.randint(1, 6)
            print(f"Your number is: {dice}")
        roll()
    else:
        print("Invalid key, press T to roll")
```